# How to transverse to a long path using terminal easily using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, path

Well i am a **beginner** to Linux environment and trying to learn some Linux commands . I find a difficulty to set my path to a particular path. When the path goes too big , I cannot type the whole path fast in a terminal. Well it doesn't suit for a **fast browsing** .Can i know how to get into a particular path faster or **by just typing few characters** of the folder name ?

This might be a silly question, But would really matter at some point of time.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [Command-line completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion), correct?  In general, type some characters, hit TAB.  If it didn't work, or you'd like more specific instructions, please edit your question and include the distribution of Linux in use, and which shell/terminal you're using.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Why not make this an answer?